# Qual seria a melhor resposta HTTP para informar o cliente que não pode excluir um registro único?

Tags: http, http-status

tenho uma aplicação onde estabeleci a seguinte regra de negócio relacionada ao cadastro dos usuários:

O usuário pode ter vários endereços vinculados a ele, porém é obrigatório que ele tenha pelo menos um endereço. Se ele tiver mais de um endereço ele tem opção de excluir os endereços a mais, porém caso ele tenha somente um, ele será impedido de exclui-lo.

Caso ele tenha somente um endereço e persista em excluir o mesmo, o sistema irá lançar uma excessão informando que não é permitido que ele exclua o endereço único.

Agora vem a dúvida, ou melhor, quero saber a opinião de vcs sobre qual seria o status de retorno HTTP mais viável para esta excessão, conceitualmente falando?

Abaixo segue alguns exemplos e o porque não quero utiliza-los caso haja algum status mais adequado:

401 Unauthorized - Até onde eu sei este status é mais aplicado a questão de login e acessos a locais não permitidos, ou seja, o usuário não tem a permissão necessária. (Estou relutante em usar este status devido ninguém no sistema poder fazer este procedimento, ou seja não há autorização para ninguém, além disso é uma operação ilegal, não pode haver usuário sem endereço na base dados)

403 Forbidden - Entendo que este status informa que a requisição é válida porém o usuário não tem permissão para executa-la (Como trata-se de uma regra de negócio este tipo de requisição é inválido, e não válida como o status sugere, por isso não o vejo como a melhor opção)

Preciso de ajuda para identificar qual seria o melhor status para este cenário levando em conta a semântica mais adequada.

Att.

Comment: Acredito que 409 conflito, da uma olhada nesse outro post no https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25122472/rest-http-status-code-if-delete-impossible

Comment: Boa Hebert, acabei seguindo por este caminho, obrigado pelo retorno. Felicidades.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Percebo duas respostas plausíveis: **200** ou **409**. Por quê?

Hoje, o protocolo HTTP prevê cinco grupos de respostas:

1. Grupo **1xx**: respostas informativas;
2. Grupo **2xx**: respostas de sucesso;
3. Grupo **3xx**: respostas de redirecionamento;
4. Grupo **4xx**: respostas de erro do cliente;
5. Grupo **5xx**: respostas de erro do servidor;

Dependendo da aplicação, podemos ter respostas personalizadas, mas não as abordarei na resposta.

A situação que nos encontramos é: um usuário vai excluir um endereço.

O **grupo 1** já descartamos sem ter que pensar muito. Não daremos nenhuma resposta provisória de cunho informativo ao cliente; então nada de resposta 100, 101 ou 102.

O **grupo 2** já nos parece um pouco interessante e eu coloquei inclusive como uma possível resposta. Aqui irá depender de questões de projeto da aplicação, pois os retornos do grupo 2xx representam respostas à requisições **que foram recebidas com sucesso, entendidas pelo servidor e aceitas**. Dependendo das especificações de projeto da sua aplicação, o servidor não permitir que o cliente exclua um endereço significa que ele recebeu a requisição com sucesso, entendeu o que deveria fazer e aceitou a requisição (cliente possui permissão para tal), mas a não exclusão do endereço poderia ser sinalizada através do corpo da resposta.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...

{
  "error": "Você possui apenas um endereço e não pode excluí-lo"
}
```

Assim, bastaria o cliente receber a resposta e tratar o corpo da mesma para verificar o sucesso da operação. Outras respostas deste mesmo grupo não acho que caberiam como possíveis respostas

O **grupo 3** também podemos eliminar sem esforço, pois não iremos fazer qualquer tipo de redirecionamento do cliente.

O **grupo 4** também parece promissor, mas vejamos cada caso.

- **400 Bad Request**: não é válido. A requisição do cliente estará no formato esperado que será compreendido pelo servidor, então retornar o erro 400 seria confuso. Basta imaginar a situação: cliente está excluindo o endereço X e retorna 400; se ele cadastrar o endereço Y e fizer novamente a exclusão de X, terá sucesso. Como poderia a mesma requisição gerar 400 e 200?
- **401 Unauthorized**: como dito na pergunta, o cliente tem autorização para excluir o endereço e cai na mesma situação que a anterior. Se houver um segundo endereço e realizar a mesma requisição, obterá sucesso. Confuso!
- **402 Payment Require**d: É, nada a ver com nossa situação.
- **403 Forbidden**: esta resposta indica que há presente dados de credenciamento na requisição, mas que o servidor julgou serem insuficientes para permitir o cliente acessar tal recurso; tanto que parte da especificação desta resposta diz que o cliente não deverá repetir a requisição com os mesmos dados de autenticação, caso contrário receberá a mesma resposta. Não estamos trabalhando com problemas de autenticação aqui.
- **404 Not Found**: achou, então esquece esse.
- **405 Method Not Allowed**: método é permitido sim, estão esquece esse também.
- **406 Not Acceptable**: resposta relacionada a negociação de conteúdo, que também não tem relação ao caso.
- **407 Proxy Authentication Required**: é, também nada a ver.
- **408 Request Timeout**: Ãhhhm, não.
- **409 Conflict**: hum, conflitos sempre são legais. Peguem suas pipocas. Brincadeiras a parte, vejamos qual a descrição desta resposta: a requisição não pode ser completada devido a conflitos com o estado atual do recurso; o cliente deverá resolver os conflitos e reenviar a requisição; o corpo da resposta deve conter informações suficientes para que o cliente identifique os conflitos. Trivial! Basta respondermos com 409 e colocar no corpo da resposta que o usuário deve cadastrar outro endereço para excluir o atual; se o fizer, ele poderá repetir a mesma requisição e obter sucesso.
- **410 Gone**: *Let it go?*
- **411 Length Required**: Náá, nada a ver.
- **412 Precondition Failed**: nome tem potencial, mas está relacionado com os cabeçalhos de condição, não com condições atuais do estado do recurso; então não!
- **413 Request Entity Too Large**: acho que não, né?
- **414 Request-URI Too Long**: cara, como você conseguiu chegar nisso?
- **415 Unsupported Media Type**: que media type? Só quero excluir o endereço, moço.
- **416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable**: mas eu nem define o range...
- **417 Expectation Failed**: desculpe não atingir suas expectativas... mas também tem relação com os cabeçalhos da requisição, não com a expectativa do usuário.

E, finalmente, **o grupo 5**. Bom, servidor está saudável, né? Esperamos que sim, então nada de erro 5xx por hoje.

Mais informações na [RFC 7231, capítulo 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6).

Comment: Muito boa a resposta Anderson, me entende perfeitamente e servirá para outras pessoas que estão na mesma situação. Obrigado.